# Are there vampires, in Assassin's Creed: Syndicate?

Tags: assassins-creed-syndicate

Are there vampires in the Victorian title, Assassin's Creed: Syndicate?

I tried looking it up, but nothing came up except trailers with vampire imagery.

Comment: We don't allow questions about games not yet released, I'm afraid.

Comment: It is released @Frank

Comment: @Jack, changing the context to present text. This may not be the best question, but your hang up is asking if there **will be**. We can tell you **if there is, now** but not *if something is expected to be coming out*.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Still, should be an easy enough thing to research.

Answer (score 3):

There are no actual vampires in Assassin's Creed: Syndicate. However, there are a few references to Dracula, which is likely what you are seeing in the trailers. The initial Dracula outfit is available with the base game. A second outfit, for Evie, and a sword, both inspired from the Dracula novel, are part of the Victorian Legends DLC.

#### [Maximum Dracula outfit](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin's_Creed:_Syndicate_outfits#Jacob.27s_outfits)

After completion of sequence 8, you will be given a schematic. For £10000, you can craft this outfit using 150 Leather, 100 Silk, and the unique material Warbar Pearl. It can be upgraded for £7500. Jacob can wear the Maximum Dracula outfit for the following benefits:

- Decreases incoming melee damage by 10-20%.
- Decreases incoming ranged damage by 10-20%.
- Increases brass knuckle damage by 10-20%.

[image: Jacob's Maximum Dracula outfit, as seen in the outfits inventory.]

### [Bloofer Lady outfit](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin's_Creed:_Syndicate_outfits#Evie.27s_outfits)

Unlocked with the purchase of the Victorian Legends DLC, Evie can wear the Bloofer Lady Outfit for the following benefits:

- Decreases incoming melee damage by 20%.
- Decreases incoming ranged damage by 20%.
- Increases kukri range by 20%.

[image: Evie's Bloofer Lady outfit, as seen from behind.]

### [Impaler Cane-Sword](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Impaler_Cane-sword)

Unlocked with the purchase of the Victorian Legends DLC, this sword has the following stats:

- Attack: 9
- Stun: 9
- Lethality: 7

[image: Close-up view of the Impaler Cane-sword, showing off the detail.]